# Why does the addslashes() function not work on my array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, session, escaping

I have a series of session variables in an array. When I use quotes in one of my string variables, I try to addslashes so I can eventually insert it into the DB, but the addslashes() function is not working. Here is an example.

In the comments field, I write this:

> **This is the "comment"**

I realize this is a problem so I added a function before I enter it into the database that runs through a series of Session variables, including the comments variable.

```
$strip_fields = array($_SESSION['comments'],$_SESSION['employee_id'],$_SESSION['approved_by'],$_SESSION['delivery_email'],$_SESSION['full_name'],$_SESSION['first_name'],$_SESSION['last_name']);

        foreach($strip_fields as $key => $value) {
            $key = addslashes($key);
        }
```

After I run this function I try to echo out the comments variable $_SESSION['comments']

> This is the "comment"

So I can see that the addslashes function somehow does not work the way I am using it. Why does the addslashes function not work the way I'm using it?

**THIS IS MY SOLUTION**  (I used a bit from both suggestions)

```
$strip_fields = array(
            'employee_id', 'approved_by', 'delivery_email', 'full_name', 
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'title', 'title_2', 'dept_div', 
            'dept_div_2', 'email', 'comments', 'special_instructions'
        );

        foreach($strip_fields as $key) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $conn->real_escape_string($_SESSION[$key]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. You are copying the values in `$_SESSION` to new variables.
2. You are passing the keys to `addslashes()`, but you placed the values into array values.
3. `foreach()` copies the values from the array into `$key` and `$value`, so you're operating on a copy of a copy.

You should be able to use references for this, but I think skipping them will be clearer.

```
$strip_fields = array(
        'comments', 'employee_id', 'approved_by', 'delivery_email', 
        'full_name', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    );

foreach($strip_fields as $key) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = addslashes($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted what I did above.

Answer (score 5):

Your question implies that you actually want to modify the contents of your `$_SESSION` variable, but this doesn't seem like a good idea, as you will just end up adding slashes again and again whenever the script is called (just an observation without having seen all your code).

Also, you shouldn't use `addslashes` to escape for a database, as each database (or database abstraction layer) has it's own way of escaping data (for example `mysql_real_escape_string` or PDO prepared statements).

Also, `$_SESSION` and a database are different ways of persisting data, and it may well be that mixing them is a bad design choice.

EDIT AFTER COMMENT...

If you want to put all those variables into the database, and prior to that they are in `$_SESSION` (which as previously stated may not be the best idea), and you are using the [mysql php module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), then you could do something like:

```
$db_names=array(
    "comments",
    "employee_id",
    "approved_by",
    "full_name",
    "first_name",
    "last_name"
);
$clean=array();
foreach($db_names as $name)
    $clean[$name]=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[$db_name]);
mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO comments_table 
        (
            comments,
            employee_id,
            approved_by,
            full_name,
            first_name,
            last_name
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '{$clean["comments"]}',
            '{$clean["employee_id"]}',
            '{$clean["approved_by"]}',
            '{$clean["full_name"]}',
            '{$clean["first_name"]}',
            '{$clean["last_name"]}'
        )
");
```

However, its best not to use the mysql module, but instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Each have different (and better, for a number of reasons) ways of escaping strings.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to mention that **`addslashes` is never the right thing to use to prepare data for an SQL insert**.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes answering the question asked isn't the right answer. :)

Comment: I value your input but that doesnt really solve my problem. So how do I fix this problem. Without the addslashes I still get a MySQL error when trying to add it into the DB since it contains quotes. Are you recommending that I just use mysql_real_escape_string instead of addslashes? Would that work in the array I have created?

Answer (score 1):

**DON'T USE `addslashes()` TO ESCAPE VALUES FOR AN SQL QUERY!** (sorry for shouting)

In the case of MySQL, your choice is `mysql_real_escape_string()` but other engines have their own escape functions. `addslashes()` is amazingly easy to "fool" if you are trying to do an SQL Injection attack.

The best thing you could do is not escaping `$_SESSION` itself, but creating a copy, and using `array_map()` along with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. This way you can keep you original unescaped version also.

```
$escaped_SESSION=array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_SESSION);
```

Others already explained why `foreach` is not the best choice for manipulating your array. It works with a copy of the array you are running it on. [`array_map()`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php&ei=mii9TZidFoXssgaTltX5BQ&usg=AFQjCNGi4f2pBEUF6XDJwPf3s9xPHMWCAw) will apply a callback to all the elements of your array, and return the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('comment' => $_SESSION['comment'], 'employee_id' => $_SESSION['employee_id']);  // other keys of session

foreach(array_keys($array) as $value){
    $array[$value] = addslashes($array[$value]);
}
```

use $array instead of using $_SESSION.

Comment: That still operates on copies of the original values from `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Use `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` instead of creating a new array containing the keys with `array_keys()`. Or use a reference with `foreach ($array as &$value) $value = addslashes($value);`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the resulting value back into the value you are echoing

```
$strip_fields = array($_SESSION['comments'],$_SESSION['employee_id'],$_SESSION['approved_by'],$_SESSION['delivery_email'],$_SESSION['full_name'],$_SESSION['first_name'],$_SESSION['last_name']);

    foreach($strip_fields as $key => $value) {
        $strip_fields[$key] = addslashes($value); // Store it back into the strip_fields var
    }
```

Also as @Gaurav noted you want to clean the array data, not the index/key.

Comment: This will overwrite the 0th, 1st, 2nd, etc. values from `$_SESSION` since `$strip_fields` doesn't contain the matching keys.

Comment: I was editing my response as you were replying.  I've updated my code after realizing his array structure.  I realize this doesn't update the `SESSION` var but I was using what he wrote thinking he may be using it elsewhere.  David's solution correctly modifies the `SESSION` var

Comment: This won't work. You cannot modify `$strip_fields` from the `foreach`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Sure you can. While `$value` is explicitly a copy (and not a reference) you can't update the value and have it be affected in the original.  However, by explicitly updating the actual array, at the given index, it will force the update.  If you wanted to do it be reference you could include the &, but I didn't want to make it more technical.  

    `foreach($strip_fields as $key => &$value){$value = addslashes($value); }`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still, what you have written in your answer is wrong, because it does not work. Thus, it is not an answer to this question. Please edit and "make it technical" as much as it is needed to give a working answer :).