# How to pass more than one argv variable using add slashes?

Tags: php, exec

I wondered what is the right syntax for passing more than one variable using the add slashes? I tried many variation until now:

```
exec('php email.php "'.addslashes($body).'"' . "'.addslashes($msg).'"');
exec('php email.php "'.addslashes($body).'"' + "'.addslashes($msg).'"'); 
exec('php email.php "'.addslashes($body).'"' & "'.addslashes($msg).'"'); 
exec('php email.php "'.addslashes($body, $msg).'"'');
```

I have already check this example with passing one argv and it's working fine:

```
exec('php email.php "'.addslashes($body).'"');
```

------------ AFTER COMMENTS -----------

The php email.php is waiting in $argv for 2 inputs in order to run right.
Therefore the main issue is how to pass him in one time 2 parameters: $body & $msg
Let say like if I ran it from web page it will be like this:

```
www.mydomain/email.php?body=value1&msg=value2
```

Comment: show us what variations you tried

Comment: Try using a `foreach` in an array, and as an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5846325/ and others in the Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/5846304/ on the same page.

Comment: please do not drop code in comments, place that in your question, it's much more easier to read.

Comment: @Fred Ok. I'll give it a try although I am using :

 $msg= $_GET['mainmsg'];

In order to get the varaibale and pass it on via the exec clm
So I hope it will work fine

Comment: @Fred-ii-The foreach is fine but the problem is with the the exec function: my php should get in one string of exec 2 input in order to work fine. With that solution I can only pass one input for one PHP file at a time